Como implementar unpacking em um objeto?
Em Python é possível fazer o unpacking de listas e outros iteráveis, atribuindo cada um dos valores em uma variável própria:
lista = [0, 1, 2]
# a=0, b=1, c=2
a, b, c = lista

# a=0, b=1, c=2
a, b, c = range(3)

Mas como fazer isso com uma classe que eu criei? Por exemplo, no código abaixo, gostaria que as variáveis nome e idade recebessem os respectivos valores que estão na instância da classe Usuario:
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
# como fazer com que "nome" e "idade" recebam os valores que estão na instância?
nome, idade = user

Claro que eu poderia fazer nome, idade = user.nome, user.idade ou criar um método que retorne esses dois campos em uma lista ou tupla. Mas tem como implementar a classe para que nome, idade = user funcione?

E mais uma vez, antes que alguém estranhe que eu mesmo respondi minha própria pergunta, isso é perfeitamente aceitável e dentro das regras. Inclusive, a página de fazer pergunta tem uma opção para postar a própria resposta junto com a pergunta. Claro que se alguém tiver outra solução, com certeza deve postá-la. O objetivo é trazer este conhecimento para o site (pois fiz uma busca e até encontrei coisas relacionadas, mas nada explicando em detalhes as opções da resposta abaixo).


A resposta abaixo é uma coletânea adaptada das respostas a esta pergunta do SOen.


Opção 1: tornar o objeto iterável
Ao rodar este código:
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
# como fazer com que "nome" e "idade" recebam os valores que estão na instância?
nome, idade = user

O erro que dá é:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Usuario object

E isso já dá a dica: para se fazer o unpacking, um objeto precisa ser iterável. Para isso, podemos implementar o método __iter__, retornando um iterador com os campos desejados:
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.nome, self.idade))

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
nome, idade = user

print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos') # Fulano tem 42 anos


Um detalhe importante em iter((self.nome, self.idade)): embora pareça redundante ter dois pares de parênteses, não é. Se eu fizer apenas iter(self.nome, self.idade), dará erro, pois neste caso estou passando dois argumentos para iter: o nome e a idade. Colocando o segundo par de parênteses, estou criando uma tupla contendo o nome e idade, e esta tupla é passada como argumento para iter.

Outra solução é implementar o método __getitem__:
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.nome, self.idade)[index]

Independente da solução escolhida, agora será possível fazer o unpacking não só na atribuição, mas também ao se passar o objeto como argumento de uma função:
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.nome, self.idade))

def faz_algo(nome, idade):
    print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos')

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
# unpacking, passa o nome no primeiro argumento, e idade no segundo
faz_algo(*user) # Fulano tem 42 anos


Opção 2: dataclass
A partir do Python 3.7, você pode usar dataclass:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass

@dataclass 
class Usuario:
    nome: str
    idade: int

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
nome, idade = user
print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos') # Fulano tem 42 anos

Um detalhe importante é que segundo a documentação, astuple retorna deep copies dos objetos. Isso pode fazer diferença dependendo do caso. Por exemplo, no código abaixo, a lista original é modificada se não usarmos dataclass:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass

@dataclass
class ComDataClass:
    nome: str
    notas: list[int]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))

c = ComDataClass('Fulano', [1, 2, 3])
nome, notas = c
# muda a nota
notas[1] = 10
# não altera a lista original (unpacking retorna uma deep copy da lista)
print(c.notas) # [1, 2, 3]

class SemDataClass:
    def __init__(self, nome, notas):
        self.nome = nome
        self.notas = notas

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.nome, self.notas))

s = SemDataClass('Fulano', [1, 2, 3])
nome, notas = s
# muda a nota
notas[1] = 10
# altera a lista original (pois unpacking retorna a mesma lista, não é feita uma cópia)
print(s.notas) # [1, 10, 3]

Uma forma de evitar a deep copy seria alterar o método __iter__ para:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class ComDataClass:
    nome: str
    notas: list[int]

    def __iter__(self):
        return (getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self))

c = ComDataClass('Fulano', [1, 2, 3])
nome, notas = c
# muda a nota
notas[1] = 10
# altera a lista original (não é mais feita a deep copy)
print(c.notas) # [1, 10, 3]

Ou seja, agora não é mais feita a deep copy da lista, então alterações feitas nela afetam a original.
Vale notar que os parênteses em volta da expressão getattr(self, etc... são obrigatórios: sem eles ocorre um erro de sintaxe, pois trata-se de uma generator expression.
Outra opção é retornar iter(self.__dict__.values()). Lembrando que a partir do Python 3.6 o atributo __dict__ garante que os campos são retornados na ordem em que foram declarados. Se quiser que os campos estejam em outra ordem, o jeito é retorná-los explicitamente em uma tupla: iter((campoX, campoY, etc)). Vale lembrar também que o atributo __dict__ só está disponível caso a classe não declare o atributo __slots__ (ver mais aqui).

Opção 3: namedtuple
Por fim, outra opção é usar namedtuple, que já dá "de bônus" a capacidade de se fazer o unpacking:
from collections import namedtuple

Usuario = namedtuple('Usuario', ['nome', 'idade'])

user = Usuario('Fulano', 42)
nome, idade = user
print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos') # Fulano tem 42 anos


Um detalhe é que, independente da solução escolhida, os nomes das variáveis não precisam bater com os das propriedades. Então nada impede que se faça a, b = user, por exemplo. Independente dos nomes, a primeira variável receberá o primeiro valor retornado pelo iterador, a segunda variável receberá o segundo valor, e assim por diante.
Vale lembrar que existem diferenças entre classe, dataclass e nametuple, que podem ou não ser relevantes depedendo de cada caso (já foge do escopo da pergunta, mas de qualquer forma, sugiro ler aqui e aqui).

Obs: A outra resposta é um ótimo complemento que resolve de forma engenhosa uma situação específica. Mas ela possui várias restrições: as variáveis devem ter os mesmos nomes dos campos da classe, e ainda exigiria um código adicional (e bem complexo) para detectar casos em que o objeto é passado para uma função, como em func(*user) ou func(*objeto_de_classe_diferente, *user).


Vale ressaltar que isso só funciona declarando as variáveis em uma ordem específica, não é possível usar nome, idade e depois idade, nome. Também pode ser usado qualquer nome para essas variáveis, já que não tem relação com os nomes das propriedades

@Costamilam De fato, tanto faz os nomes das variáveis, é um detalhe que passou batido. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

@Costamilam Fiz uma resposta complementando essa que contornaria essa limitação

Como forma de complementar a outra resposta, aplicando a solução de criar um objeto iterável a partir do método __iter__ podemos utilizar a instrospecção e avaliar a linha de código onde o unpacking é executado para obternos quais são os atributos de interesse e adaptar o retorno.
Isso é possível porque quando o Python vai executar o unpacking ele chama implicitamente a função __iter__ do objeto, então podemos tratar isso como sendo uma chamada de função normal, em que basta pegarmos o contexto de onde a chamada é feita e analisar.

Importante já salientar que a solução aqui é apenas para exemplicar o princípio e se for utilizar em sua aplicação, faça por sua conta em risco e, principalmente, avalie as possiveis otimizações no código. Aqui não me importei com performance, segurança ou mesmo boas práticas, mas isso não desqualifica a solução.

No Python podemos utilizar o pacote inspect para fazer a introspecção e através da pilha de chamadas obter o contexto no qual a função __iter__ foi chamada. A partir do contexto, podemos obter o código Python e analisá-lo de forma a extrair o nome das variáveis que compõem o unpacking. Com o nome das variáveis, ajustamos o retorno da função para retornar os valores dos atributos referente à essas variáveis, na ordem que foram definidas.
De forma bem simplista:
import inspect
import re
 
 
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
 
    def __iter__(self):
        # Obtém a pilha de chamadas
        stack = inspect.stack()

        # Obtém o segundo contexto da pilha, posição 1 (posição 0 é o contexto local da própria função)
        frame = stack[1]

        # Obtém a linha de código que foi feita a chamada da função
        code = frame.code_context[0]
 
        # Valida se o código é um unpacking em uma lista
        match = re.search(r'\[(.*)\] :?= .*', code)
        if match:
            # Obtém os nomes das variáveis que receberão os valores do unpacking
            attributes = (attr.strip() for attr in match[1].split(','))

            # Retorna os valores dos atributos na ordem definida (e somente os necessários)
            return iter(getattr(self, attr) for attr in attributes)
 
        raise AttributeError

Assim, possuindo o objeto user = User('Woss', 99), podemos fazer as seguintes chamadas com unpacking:
[name] = user
print(name)  # Woss

[name, age] = user
print(name, age)  # Woss 99

[age] = user
print(age)  # 99

[age, name] = user
print(age, name)  # 99 Woss

[foo] = user  # AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'foo'

Ou seja, desta forma o comportamento é bastante semelhante ao unpacking de objetos do JavaScript, porém desta forma, como está aqui, não seria possível fazer o unpacking com o asterísco, *user. Se for de interesse que funcione também para essa sintaxe bastaria ajustar a lógica no método __iter__ retornando todos os atributos.

Obviamente que expressão regular não é a melhor solução para analisar o código Python da chamada. O próprio Python já possui um pacote chamado ast que pode ser utilizado para gerar a árvore de tokens da linha a ser interpretada e com ela não só validar se é um unpacking como obter os nomes das variáveis no contexto.
Por exemplo, nesse caso poderiamos fazer:
import ast


tree = ast.parse('[name, age] = user')

E teríamos um objeto parecido com esse:
Module(
  body=[
    Assign(
      targets=[
        List(
          elts=[
            Name(id='name'),
            Name(id='age')
          ]
        )
      ],
      value=Name(id='user')
    )
  ]
)

Para obter a lista de nome das variáveis, tal como fizemos no exemplo, bastaria fazer:
attributes = [attr.id for attr in tree.body[0].targets[0].elts]
# ['name', 'age']

